# Difference between full copy and restore backup

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

Do you have any idea about what is the difference between doing a Full copy instance from organization A to B and restore a backup from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

Full copy is instance to instance. You can't copy 'image' of instance, two days ago. You are limited to the current image of source instance.

Restore is instance backup to instance. You can restore an 'image of an instance' up to 3 days ago. You can choose from several backups/image for your target instance.